# Why is the same Youtube API request returning 401 in a different project?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, credentials, http-status-code-401

I am fetching playlistItems from the Youtube Data API via this URL:

```
URL = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C%20contentDetails&playlistId=${playlistId}&maxResults=${50}&pageToken=${nextPageToken}&key=${API_KEY}`
```

it works fine in a project I'm using for experimentation.

Now it was time to copy  the code into my actual application.

The only thing I changed was that I put the API_Key inside my .env and set it via:

```
const API_KEY = process.env.YT_API_KEY
```

I still don't understand why, but the URL ends up having key=undefined at the end:
[image]

I am setting it inside .env like this:
[image]

**Now to the real reason why I'm seeking help:**
To fix the issue, I set the API_KEY directly inside the file that makes the fetch.

But I get the same 401 error as above (except key= is not undefined anymore)

*And when I click the link in the error message, I can look at the JSON object, that I seek. So the URL is definitely working.* As it (still) does in my other project.

**So what leads to the 401 error then?**

I had the idea, that maybe I need to change something in the cloud platform credentials settings. But my API key doesn't have any restrictions.

Comment: unauthorized (401)   when you created this new api key where did you create it exactly?  is it in the same project as before or did you create a new project?

Comment: it works in one project. not in another (older) project. both are on localhost: 3000

Comment: But is it the same API key?   Ok heres a fun one double check that your api key isnt getting cut off i have seen env vars get eaten sometimes.   Also check that the encoding isnt getting messed up it needs to get http encoded to go to the api.

Comment: I want to emphasize, that rightclick>open in new tab> on the link shown in the 401 error shows me the JSON objects that I'm asking for.

Comment: it's the exact same request URL with the same key

Answer (score 0):

Problem: The application is setting a global header via axios.

Solution: using fetch() instead